# Get owner of socket in OS X kernel extension

Tags: macos, sockets, kernel

I am writing a Mac OS X NKE which places a socket filter. One I receive a socket, I need to get the PID of the socket's owner. I have tried the FIOGETOWN ioctl, but I receive an errno of 102 (Operation not supported on socket). Is there any way to get the owner's PID?

Answer (score 5):

I found it! Apparently, when the attach callback of a socket filter executes, you are executing in the context of the process that created the socket. A simple call to proc_selfpid() gives the PID.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this. for this project: https://github.com/furkanmustafa/yafw4osx

Comment: `proc_selfpid` may lead to unexpected results. See https://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2006/Oct/msg00166.html